# Showing unmatched word in elasticsearch results

Tags: elasticsearch, match

I want to display which words are not matched by a multi-word query for returned documents. Is there a query type, or parameter to achieve this?

Normally, such unmatched words are shown to the users in strikethrough typeface:

[image: Missing word]

---

**Example query after I got the answer:**

```
POST /posts/_search
{
   "query": {
      "bool": {
         "should": [
            {"match": {"name": {"query": "jogging rain"}}},
            {"match": {"name": {"query": "jogging", "_name": "jogging"}}},
            {"match": {"name": {"query": "rain", "_name": "rain"}}}
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Now if we find a document with the word `jogging` but not `rain`, we'd get a result like this:

```
{
    "_source": {
        "name": "jogging"
    },
    "matched_queries": [
        "jogging"
    ]
}
```

Then in the next step I subtract the contents of `matched_queries`, i.e. `"jogging"` from the initial search, i.e. `"jogging rain"` and the result: `"rain"` is what I want.

Thanks @Val for the idea on how to solve this!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [named queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.2/search-request-named-queries-and-filters.html) for this, by giving a name to each of your queries. In the results, each hit will feature a `matched_queries` array containing the names of the queries that matched (e.g. `unmatched_query` and `strikethrough_query` below). You can then use that info on the client-side to build a strikethrough list of words which didn't match.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "content": {
              "query": "unmatched",
              "_name": "unmatched_query"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "content": {
              "query": "strikethrough",
              "_name": "strikethrough_query"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Interesting approach, I'll try it out and play with it. Does it mean, that I'd have to split the initial query into words and check each separately whether it matched?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea. Check if that works for you and if not we can go a bit further.

Comment: Great, now I see! So you propose to split the multiword query into as many queries as words, name each of those queries with exactly the word and then subtract query names from the initial words. The result are the unmatched words. Very clever. thanks!

Comment: @Val what about search-time synonyms? They can be based on multiple tokens and could be the only match. If we split them up they might not match anything despite having matched in the full query.

There are also stop words and shingles. What would you do to handle those cases where terms will only match something given the full context of the search?

Comment: @Kosi you're talking about a different case, feel free to create a dedicated question for your need

Comment: I've created https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69651744/elasticsearch-display-words-missed-from-query?noredirect=1&lq=1 for this use case. Please let me know if anything is unclear and I can update